# Escaping the "|" sign in java

Tags: java, string

I need to split a spring delimited by "|". When I use `String.split("|")` it doesn't give me the correct result.

`String[] arr = "1234|5678".split("|"); 
 System.out.println(arr[1]); \\ This prints "1"`

I've tried using the escape character `"\"` but I get an Invalid escape sequence error from Eclipse.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand that there are two levels of escaping here:

- String literal escaping
- Regular expression escaping

You want a regular expression with the pattern `\|` - but in order to write that as a string literal, you need to escape the `\`, so you end up with:

```
split("\\|")
```

Another alternative is to use something like [Guava's `Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) which is simpler to use because it doesn't treat strings as regular expressions - although it does allow you to specify a `Pattern` when you *want* a regular expression:

```
Splitter splitter = Splitter.on('|');
...
List<String> list = splitter.splitToList("1234|5678");
```

Answer (score 3):

`|` is regular expression character meaning empty string,

So you need to escape it, like

```
"1234|5678".split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String.split("\\|")
```

You want to split the string on `\|`, to escape the pipe. But to represent `\|` as a string, you need to escape the `\`. So you do `"\\|"`.